# Sorting collection of posts in latest version of Assemble

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, assemble

I’m trying to migrate an old site I have from [grunt-assemble](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble) over to [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) (with [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp)).

I’ve managed to work out a lot of the differences but I’m not really sure how collections now work and how to make a collection of posts and then sort them.

The old config I had in grunt-assemble was like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  assemble: {
    posts: {
      options: {
        collections: [{
          name: 'post',
          sortby: 'posted',
          sortorder: 'descending'
        }],
        permalinks: {
          structure: ':url.html'
        }
      },
      files: [{
        cwd: './src/templates/pages/blog/',
        dest: '<%= site.destination %>/blog',
        expand: true,
        src: ['**/*.hbs', '**/*.md']
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

How can I convert this to work in the latest version of Assemble?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [`{{items}}` helper from assemble-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-helpers#items) and the [withSort](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers#withsort) helper from [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers) to accomplish your goal:

```
{{#withSort "data.posted" (items "posts") reverse=true}}
  {{this.data.title}}
{{/withSort}}
```

This also assumes that you've created a "posts" view collection and you're loading your "posts" into it:

```
// create the "posts" view collection (usually done outside of a task)
app.create('posts');

// load markdown posts into the "posts" view collection (usually done in a "load" task
app.posts('path/to/posts/*.md');
```